# Duplicate log lines in vscode when debugging ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

When debugging a typical ASP.NET Core app with one of the default templates, I am faced with duplicate log lines in the DEBUG CONSOLE, e.g.:

[image]

It is extremely annoying because it makes the log difficult to read by constantly switching indentation and with repetitions. I have not configured any logging in Program.cs nor in Startup.cs, so the default configuration is doing this.

Why is it doing this, and can I remove it?

I thought maybe the root cause was because CreateDefaultBuilder(...) adds both debug and console logging. So I tried rolling my own:

```
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                //logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
            })
```

But that had no effect.

Comment: As far as I remember, that's the default console log format. The first line is an overview of the log and the following lines is the expanded, detailed version. Switch to Serilog, NLog or your favorite logger if you don't like that format

Comment: Not correct.  The dupicate logs are due to the console logging being directed to the debug console in addition to the debug logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dupicate logs are due to the

**console logging**

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

being directed to the debug console by default in vscode in addition to the

**debug logging.**

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

You can either separate console logging using launch.json

```
"console":"integratedTerminal"
```

Or as you where trying to do remove the debug logging.
Note you need to add ClearProviders()

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
      logging.ClearProviders();
      logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
      logging.AddConsole();
      //logging.AddDebug();
      logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
})
```

Please also see
[Remove console and debug loggers in ASP.NET Core 2.0 when in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986517/remove-console-and-debug-loggers-in-asp-net-core-2-0-when-in-production-mode?answertab=active#tab-top)