# Prevent .NET from logging to the console?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, .net-6.0, ilogger

I have implemented dependency injection in my application. And I configuration services as follows.

```
IConfiguration configuration = context.Configuration;

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

services.ConfigureRailIncApi(configuration);

services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

services.AddSingleton(configuration);
services.AddSingleton(Logger);

services.AddSingleton<Application>();
services.AddSingleton<ServiceManager>();
```

This all works fine except now the framework is logging to the console, including the contents of any queries sent to the database.

Somehow the internal logging has been enabled but I don't see where I've enabled it.

How can I prevent .NET from logging to the screen?

*Note: `Logger` is an instance of my own logging class `ConsoleLogger`. This class does not implement `ILogger` or use anything else from .NET. It is simply a custom class that also logs to the console and a file. Logging from this logger is working fine. And I've confirmed the .NET logs are not being sent to this class.*

**Update:**

Here's my code that configures the host.

```
public void Configure(string[] args, Action< HostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection> configureServices, Action<IHostBuilder> configureHost)
{
    IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

    hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton(this);
        configureServices(context, services);
    });

    configureHost(hostBuilder);

    AppHost = hostBuilder.Build();
}
```

And here's the code that calls it.

```
ApplicationServices appServices = new();

appServices.Configure(args, (context, services) =>
{
    IConfiguration configuration = context.Configuration;

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });

    services.ConfigureRailIncApi(configuration);

    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

    services.AddSingleton(configuration);
    services.AddSingleton(Logger);

    services.AddSingleton<Application>();
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceManager>();
},
builder =>
{

});
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Core app? IIRC, that logs to the console by default, and I don't see anywhere that you're removing the clearing the default log providers.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, .NET 6.0. That's what's happening. But I can't see where this can be disabled. Also, it doesn't happen without my DI code. I'm enabling it somehow.

Comment: A [mcve] would be really helpful at this point. It's hard to say any more based on just what you've shown, to be honest.

Comment: This code does not log database queries to the console. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Copy this code to a new app and you'll see it doesn't exhibit the behavior your describe. Perhaps the contents of `ConfigureRailIncApi()` might be relevant.

Comment: @CodeCaster: None of my code logs database queries to the console. It's coming from the framework.

Comment: Then what do you mean by _"except now the framework is logging to the console, including the contents of any queries"_? You show very common DI code which does not do what you claim it does.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I'm not clear on what part wasn't clear. I'm seeing logging from the framework to the console, and it includes my SQL queries. I have no idea what you think I claimed my DI code does. I just showed it to show that I am not configuring logging.

Comment: Shall I repeat myself as well then? This code you show does not configure console logging, nor does it configure logging database queries. Create a [mre]. Just "implementing DI" doesn't add logging, you do. Show that code.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That was the point. I have no code that adds or configures logging. If I did, I would gladly show it to you. But I just don't.

Comment: You do, though. It's simply not shown. You have a HostBuilder somewhere, for example.

Comment: One of extensions called is adding logging internally. Usually you would need to explicitly clear the loggers. The shown code is incomplete so I doubt we can reproduce this problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I've posted the code that builds the host.

Comment: @Nkosi: I'm pretty sure you're right but I can't see what I'm calling that does this. I've posted the code that builds the host.

Comment: Note where they say which providers are added by default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#logging-providers

Comment: You want to call `ClearProviders();` on the logger of the builder and only add the ones you want

Comment: @Nkosi: The `IHostBuilder` returned from `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` does not have a `Logging` property for me.

Comment: Then you most likely need to call the extension for configuring logging `hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging (logBuilder => logBuilder.ClearProviders());` Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.configurelogging

Comment: @Nkosi: I saw that. But it has no `ClearProviders()` method either. I don't know if that's all different because it's not a web app. Do you think logging is getting enabled by default?

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes it does. It is an extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggingbuilderextensions.clearproviders?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggingBuilderExtensions_ClearProviders_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggingBuilder_

Comment: @Nkosi: Hitting Ctrl+. doesn't show any options. Do I need to install a logging package so that I can disable logging? :-) Do you think it's getting disabled by default?

Comment: That last link I provided shows the namespace and assembly where the extension exists

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes, okay. I had to explicitly specify that `configureLogging` was of type `ILoggingBuilder` for some reason. I should be able to clear it this way. Thanks for your help. Is your understanding that the default host builder adds logging by default?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 for what that does. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986517/remove-console-and-debug-loggers-in-asp-net-core-2-0-when-in-production-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

> The `CreateDefaultBuilder` method:
> ...
> ...
> Adds the following logging providers:
>
> - Console
> - Debug
> - EventSource
> - EventLog (only when running on Windows)

Reference [Default builder settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#default-builder-settings)

You would need to explicitly remove the default providers and add only the ones you want.

```
IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

//...

hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging(logging => {
    logging.ClearProviders();

    //... add my providers here
});

//...
```

Note that if you want to avoid other extension adding their own providers, then perform the logging configuration last so that you are sure about which loggers were added.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what's happening. I'm not sure why `ConfigureLogging` assumed the `logging` parameter was of type `HostBuilderContext` but I was able to force it to be `ILoggingBuilder`. Thanks for your help.