# How to get absolute path of running App using IHostBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, environment-variables, app-config, ilogger

I have created a class library for custom logger and register my logger to `windows` or `web application` using extension method on `IHostBuilder`. I want to create `"Log"` folder (if not exists) in directory were `Program.cs` file exists. With `console application` I can create directory using relative path Directory.CreateDirectory(@"......\Logs") and it creates directory in desired location. However when my logger is registered with `WebApp` it creates directory in "F:\Logs\CsvILogger.csv".

```
public static IHostBuilder RegisterMyLoggerWithDefaultSettings(this IHostBuilder builder)
{
   //How can I get absolute path of program.cs file here with web application?

}
```

How can I get path to folder where "program.cs" file exists when my logger is registered to WebApplication?

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea to find the solution from this post: [remove specific logging provider from the services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58329479/5139020)

**Note:** For getting Webroot path I used reflection to extract property value because I don't want to add reference to `Asp.Net core library` in my class library where this extesion methord resides. I have only added package reference of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` in my class library.

```
public static IHostBuilder FindApplicationPath(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
            {
                var serviceDescriptor = loggingBuilder.Services.Where(x => x.ImplementationInstance != null && x.ServiceType.FullName == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment").FirstOrDefault();
                string appPath;
                if (serviceDescriptor != null)
                {
                    //application is web application
                    appPath = serviceDescriptor.ImplementationInstance
                                     .GetType()
                                     .GetProperty("WebRootPath")
                                     .GetValue(serviceDescriptor.ImplementationInstance, null)
                                     .ToString();
                    //code to use path
                }
                else
                {
                    serviceDescriptor = loggingBuilder.Services
                                        .Where(x => x.ImplementationInstance != null && 
                                                                   x.ServiceType == typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment))
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
                    var hostingEnvironment = (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironment)serviceDescriptor.ImplementationInstance;
                    appPath = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
                     
                      //code to use path
                }

            }
        );
        return builder;
    }
```

**Output:**

Web-App:

Z:\Folder1\Folder2\MyWebApp\wwwroot

Console-App:

Z:\MyConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net6.0